# In Ruby, during iteration of an array, how do I send multiple array elements as values for one specific hash key?

Tags: arrays, ruby, iteration

I know how to iterate through an array and I know how to create hash keys and values. I do not know how to create an array for the value and pass it multiple elements. My desired value for `hash` below is:
`{'abc' => [1, 2, 3] , 'def' => [4,5,6,7]}`

How would I achieve this hash, while iterating through array `a` and `b` below using `each`?

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
c = [1,2,3]
b = ['abc', 'def']

hash = {}
```

Comment: You cannot “add multiple values for one key”.  You can add or modify one value which is an array. — This seems an odd goal. Is it homework?

Comment: This is not homework, it is something I've been running into in some exercises I've been doing. To your point, the more accurate question would be how do I make my keys arrays, adding one element at a time to them during iteration of the original array?

Note: I will update question now

Comment: Yes, this will be a lot easier if the values are all arrays, even when there is only one entry in an array.

Comment: So what is the logic here? How do you “know” from your two arrays that 1,2,3 “belong” to “abc”?

Comment: Another good point. I have added array `c` to give logic to the example. I have removed the `'ghi'` key to simplify the logic. While iterating through array `a`, if the element of iteration is included in array `c`, it is passed to the array value within key `'abc'`. Otherwise, it is passed to other array value in key `'def'`. Thank you for bearing with me while I optimize the question

Comment: I think you should come back when you know what the problem even is. You may need several sets of input-plus-desired-output. It’s like tying your shoes, you can’t teach a computer to do it until you know how _you_ do it.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this question turned out not to be as interesting as I was hoping. I was hoping that the problem was this:

*Knowing the hash key and a value, how can I make sure the key's value is an array and that the given value is appended to that?*

For instance, start with `h` being `{}`. I have a key name `:k` and a value `1`. I want `h[:k]`, if it doesn't already exist, to be `[1]`. But if it does already exist, then it's an array and I want to append `1` to that array; for instance, if `h[:k]` is already `[3,2]`, now it should be `[3,2,1]`.

I can think of various ways to ensure that, but one possibility is this:

```
(hash[key] ||= []) << value
```

To see that this works, let's make it a method:

```
def add_to_hash_array_value(hash:, key:, value:)
  (hash[key] ||= []) << value
end
```

Now I'll just call that a bunch of times:

```
h = {}
add_to_hash_array_value(hash:h, key:"abc", value:1)
add_to_hash_array_value(hash:h, key:"abc", value:2)
add_to_hash_array_value(hash:h, key:"def", value:4)
add_to_hash_array_value(hash:h, key:"def", value:5)
add_to_hash_array_value(hash:h, key:"abc", value:3)
puts h #=> {"abc"=>[1, 2, 3], "def"=>[4, 5]}
```

We got the right answer.

This is nice because suppose I have some way of knowing, given a value, what key it should be appended to. I can just repeatedly apply that decision-making process.

However, the trouble with trying to apply that to the original question is that the original question seems not to know exactly *how* to decide, given a value, *what* key it should be appended to.

Answer (score 1):

From your guidelines given in the comment:

> While iterating through array a, if the element of iteration is included in array c, it is passed to the array value within key 'abc'. Otherwise, it is passed to other array value in key 'def'

You can do this:

```
hash = {}
hash['abc'] = a.select { |x| c.include?(x) }
hash['def'] = a.reject{ |x| c.include?(x) }
```

See [Enumerable#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) and [Enumerable#reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject). Also can take a look at [Enumerable#partition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) which would be another good choice here, where you want to split an array into two arrays based on some condition:

```
in_a, not_in_a = a.partition { |x| c.include?(x) }
hash = { 'abc' => in_a, 'def' => not_in_a }
```

You can also do it with regular `each` if these fancy enumerable methods are bit too much for you:

```
hash = { 'abc' => [], 'def' => [] }

a.each do |x|
  if c.include?(x)
    hash['abc'].push(x)
  else
    hash['def'].push(x)
  end
end
```